# Передача параметров переменной другим функциям

Tags: javascript, файлы

Есть вот такая функция:

```
var p;

function readFile(fileEntry) {
    fileEntry.file(function (file) {
        p = 'Name: ' + file.name + 'Last Modified: ' + new Date(file.lastModifiedDate) + 'Size: ' + file.size;
    });
}
```

дальше я её вызываю переменную p в другой функции:

```
function listResults(entries) {
    entries.forEach(function (entry) {
        if (entry.isDirectory) {
            //....
        } else {
            readFile(entry);
            console.log(p);
        }
    });
}
```

Переменная не отдает то, что я присвоил, а пишет undefined, что это может быть? Как можно на моем конкретном примере решить эту проблему? Давным давно мучаю этот вопрос, никто не может помочь. Помогите, пожалуйста. Использую File API для JS.

Первая функция получает данные по файлам, вторая должна вывести эти данные.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если верно утверждение из прошлого вопроса, что fileEntry.file() - асинхронный, то задача меняется.

Так как переместить дальнейшую обработку в коллбэк функции вряд ли устроит (насколько я понял вы хотите информацию по всем файлам отправить одним запросом), то остается второй вариант:

Написать отдельную функцию которая будет проверять пришли ли все ответы на посланные запросы и только после этого будет обрабатывать полученные данные. Добавить счетчик, который будет считать кол-во посланных и полученных данных (при отправке запроса увеличиваем счетчик на 1, при получении данных уменьшаем). Если счетчик отличный от нуля, значит не все данные еще пришли.

Пример на скорую руку. Можно уже работать в данном направлении для достижения нужного результата.

```
var p=[], k=0; //объявляем счетчик и массив для данных
function readFile(fileEntry){
    fileEntry.file(function(file){
        p.push('Name: '+file.name+ //пушим данные в массив для дальнейшей обработки
            'Last Modified: '+new Date(file.lastModifiedDate)+
            'Size: '+file.size);
        k--; //понижаем счетчик (данные записались)
        sendResults(); // вызываем функцию для обработки данных
    });
}
function listResults(entries) {
    entries.forEach(function(entry) {
        if (entry.isDirectory) {
            //....
        } else {
            k++; //увеличиваем счетчик (данные запросили)
            readFile(entry);
        }
    });
}
function sendResults(){ //функция для отправки данных 
    if(k==0){ //если счетчик 0, значит полученных ответов столько же сколько отправленных запросов. Можно готовить данные к отправке
      console.log(p.join('|'));
    }
}
```

P.S. извиняюсь, слишком на быструю. Надо еще проверять общее количество файлов я думаю. Так как если первый же readFile(entry); отработает очень быстро (раньше чем отправится следующий в forEach()), то функция отправки сработает с частью данных.

Comment: добавил пример

Comment: @dajver - еще раз "тонко намекаю". Выучите матчасть, прочтите пару книг, попишите немного академического кода. Или вы до старости будете на hashcode писать по любому вопросу связанному с javascript? :)

Comment: Я уже разобрался, спасибо @iKuzko, за это!

Answer (score 1):

```
function readFile(fileEntry){
    var p;    
    fileEntry.file(function(file){ 
       ...    
    });
    return p;    
}
```

а потом, вместо

```
readFile(entry);
console.log(p);
```

просто

```
console.log(readFile(entry));
```

---

> как выяснилось, что fileEntry.file() асинхронный

```
function readFile(fileEntry, callback){
    fileEntry.file(function(file){ 
       callback('Name: '+file.name+...);
    });   
}
```

и в дальнейшем:

```
readFile(entry, console.log);
```

Comment: Это пройденный этап. Так мы пытались до того как выяснилось, что fileEntry.file() асинхронный :)

Comment: Возвращает undefined